# Fluent nhibernate table-per-subclass want to return items of base class type without joining to child tables

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have classes like this:

```
public class BasicSearchResult
{
    public virtual int ItemID { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
public class AdvancedSearchResult : BasicSearchResult
{
    public virtual string DetailedData { get; set; }
}
public class BasicSearchResultMap : ClassMap<BasicSearchResult>
{
    public BasicSearchResultMap()
    {
        Table("BASIC_SEARCH_VIEW");
        ReadOnly();

        Id(x => x.ItemID).Column("ITEM_ID").GeneratedBy.Assigned();
        Map(x => x.Name).Column("PRODUCT_NAME");
    }
}
public class AdvancedSearchResultMap : SubclassMap<AdvancedSearchResult>
{
    public AdvancedSearchResultMap()
    {
        Table("ADVANCED_SEARCH_VIEW");
        KeyColumn("ITEM_ID");
        Map(x => x.DetailedData).Column("EXTRA_DATA");
    }
}
```

Where both basic & advanced views have the exact same items (but vastly more horizontal data behind the advanced view).

This all works fine, and I can retrieve this from the database fine.  The issue I want to change is I want to still be able to retrieve JUST the BasicSearchResult data sometimes without joining into the ADVANCED_SEARCH_VIEW because that query is expensive.

In other words, I only want to retrieve a subclass when I explicitly ask for it. But, even when i ask for just BasicSearchResult, nhibernate is being overly helpful and always attempting to join into the ADVANCED_SEARCH_VIEW.

Does anyone know a way to ensure that there will only be a join into the subclass when i explicitly ask for that subclass?

Putting it another way, when i do

```
session.Get<BasicSearchResult>(99);
```

it results in this sql:

```
SELECT
    this_.ITEM_ID,
    this_.PRODUCT_NAME,
    case 
        when this_1_.ITEM_ID is not null then 1
        when this_.ITEM_ID is not null then 0
    end                            as clazz_2_
    this_1_.EXTRA_DATA
FROM   BASIC_SEARCH_VIEW this_
       left outer join ADVANCED_SEARCH_VIEW this_1_
         on this_.ITEM_ID = this_1_.ITEM_ID
WHERE  
    this_.ITEM_ID = 99
```

When i really just want to have:

```
SELECT
    this_.ITEM_ID,
    this_.PRODUCT_NAME
FROM   BASIC_SEARCH_VIEW this_
WHERE  
    this_.ITEM_ID = 99
```

Or - am i completely off base and should be using Join() to do this kind of thing?

Thanks for any help on the subject.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I retrieve a list of base class objects without joins using NHibernate ICriteria?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884263/how-do-i-retrieve-a-list-of-base-class-objects-without-joins-using-nhibernate-ic)

Comment: Other possible duplicate: [NHibernate query baseclass without left joins to derived classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666819/nhibernate-query-baseclass-without-left-joins-to-derived-classes)

Answer (score 0):

### Option 1

```
session.Query<BasicSearchResult>()
    .Select(res => new BasicSearchResult
    {
        ItemID = res.ItemID,
        Name = res.Name,
    }).ToList();
```

### Option 2

use aliasToBeanTransformer

### Option 3

write a specialised mapping